# How to edit months .datepicker()-widget

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am using the code below to create a datepicker.

With `dayNamesMin` I can change the way the days are shown.

How can I edit the months?

```
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
monthNamesShort: [ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
                   "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro",
                   "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" ]
```